# Why does the definition of the riskless asset vary in discrete vs continuous time?

Tags: market-model, theory

In a multi-period market model, let's say we have $d+1$ assets $(S^0,S)=(S^0,S^1,\dots,S^d) $, where $S^0$ is the riskless asset, invested in a money market account. In continuous-time finance I usually see this asset defined as $S_t^0=e^{rt}$ and in discrete-time finance i often see it defined as $S_t^0=(1+r)^t$. Is there any reason that the definitions differ, other than $(1+r)^t$ being easier to calculate in discrete time? Thanks for clearing up my confusion!

Comment: Hi: My best guess would be because, in continuous time, interest is assume to compound continuously and, in discrete time, it is assumed to compound discretely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us say we have a yearly interest rate of $r$ that compounds over $n$ periods. With annual compounding that means $n=1$, with semi-annual compounding that means $n=2$ and with daily compounding that means $n=365$.

We can calculate the value of putting \$1 into the bank account at time zero and withdrawing it after $n$ periods at time $t$ as
$$
 \left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^{nt}
$$
For the case of continuous time it is assume that interest is compounded continuously making the number of periods go towards infinity
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^{nt}=e^{rt}
$$
So the continuous time bank account is just the continuous limit of the discrete time bank account.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!